# Need help pushing a new branch to remote

Tags: git

I am new to git, and I am trying to push a new branch to bitbucket. I already have a branch called master.

But  what I want to do is push a branch with a different name to the same remote repo in bitbucket, without downloading the files for the master branch

Here is the issue that I am facing. When I initialize a new repo and do my first commit it automatically creates a master branch.. I coundln't find a way to change the name of the master branch

So  I created a new branch called "database". However I am unable to add the files to the staging index for database branch because they have already been committed to the master branch

Is there a way where I can just create a new branch, commit the files to the new branch and push it to the remote server as another branch?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You could use something like [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) ...

Comment: @jrenk these three dots at the end make your comment mean :/

Comment: I didnt meant it that way. I just use them all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the `database` branch, the staging area already contained all of the files that were in the branch you branched from. So all you should need to do is `push origin database`, and the branch will be up there.

Comment: I see.. That did indeed work. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to branch out from master. As you said, all the files in master are actually the files you need in database file. So, in your terminal, inside the repo folder do the following:

```
git checkout database
git push -u origin database
```

The local database branch will be visible on remote.